# How to keep cursor vertically aligned to center even at the end of buffer?

Tags: scrolling, cursor

I would like to keep my cursor centered vertically as I type away in insert mode even when I reach the end of the buffer I am editing (at which point I would like the virtual lines starting with `~` to populate the screen, or something similar). From [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/how-to-center-a-cursor-on-the-screen-even-at-the-start-of-the-file), I understand that it may be impossible to do this at the top of the file, but since I almost always edit at the bottom, I was wondering if it is possible to maintain this behavior at the bottom of the file. Specifically, this is the behavior I would like to have:

1. As I type or scroll in insert or normal mode at the middle of a long file, the cursor should remain vertically centered.
2. As I reach the bottom, I would like the cursor to remain vertically centered and the screen be populated with virtual lines.
3. If I type at the top, I don't mind the cursor not being vertically centered.

Here is what I have tried:

1. `set scrolloff = 999`. This works well in the middle of the file, but does not work at the bottom.
2. Remapping scroll keys to append the `zz` command. This works well in normal mode even at the end of the file, but does not work in insert mode.
3. Running `zz` in an `autocmd` in insert mode. Specifically, I tried both of the following:

```
au InsertCharPre * norm zz
au TextChangedI,TextChangedP * norm zz
```

Both work, but both have the one weird effect. At the end of a line, whenever I type something, the cursor is positioned before the inserted character. That is, representing cursor with `|`,

```
End of line|        <- I type the character '.' here
End of line|.       <- The cursor is now positioned before the '.'
```

Note that this happens only at the end of a line. At the middle of a line, things seem to work fine. This seems to be a quirk of `norm`, and maybe somehow running different commands in the `autocmd` based on weather the cursor is at the end of the line will work, but I feel like there should be a shorter way to achieve what I want.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the cursor position at the end of the line with a little extra Vimscript:

```
augroup KeepCentered
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * normal! zz
  autocmd TextChangedI * call InsertRecenter()
augroup END

function InsertRecenter() abort
  let at_end = getcursorcharpos()[2] > len(getline('.'))
  normal! zz

  " Fix position of cursor at end of line
  if at_end
    let cursor_pos = getcursorcharpos()
    let cursor_pos[2] = cursor_pos[2] + 1
    call setcursorcharpos(cursor_pos[1:])
  endif
endfunction
```

This is essentially the "running different commands in the autocmd based on whether the cursor is at the end of the line" solution that you rejected in your question, but it feels cleaner to me than my old answer, which involved mapping keys in insert mode:

### Old (accepted) answer

#### Normal/visual mode

For normal/visual mode, rather than remapping scroll commands, I would use an autocommand:

```
augroup KeepCentered
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * normal! zz
augroup END
```

#### Insert mode

For insert mode, as you've discovered, simple autocommands won't suffice. Instead, note that there are very few keystrokes that can cause the cursor to change lines when in insert mode: you can remap these to keep the cursor line centred:

```
inoremap <CR> <C-\><C-O><C-E><CR>
inoremap <BS> <BS><C-O>zz
nnoremap o <C-E>o
```

(I don't use the arrow keys, but if you use these in insert mode, you can remap `<up>` and `<down>` similarly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This almost works, but has only one problem: when editing `/* * */` style comment blocks, the single space worth of indent inserted after the middle `*` is gone. I could add something like `.<bs><c-o>zz` instead, but then other problems happen. Please look at this other question I posted: [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/how-to-disable-auto-insertion-of-comment-header-when-pressing-enter-but-keep-au)

Comment: @Diggs I updated my answer to use `<C-\><C-O>` instead, which solves the issue you raise.

Comment: but this prevents auto closing of comment blocks by just typing `/`.  At the and of the comment block, If I type `/`, I get ` * /` when I want to have ` */`.

Comment: @Diggs see my update.

Comment: @Diggs and see my updated update for a simpler solution!

Comment: Works great, thank you so much. It's weird that `zz` prevents comments from being auto closed, but `<c-e>` works fine... do you know why this is?

Comment: @Diggs The Ctrl-E doesn't affect the comments because we're doing it _before_ we emulate the press of `Enter`, so when you type `/` it is still the first thing on the line. My [previous edit went into more detail about why the `zz` version was breaking comment closing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/revisions/26055/3). After writing it I realised we could side-step the issue with the current solution.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks.

Comment: For anyone that has trouble with the insert-mode remaps messing up other Enter keybindings (like COC auto-complete), try moving the COC import after the above remap in your init.. That seems to allow both to work fine.